# Adding the default signature to Outlook email

Tags: vba, vb.net, outlook, office-interop

I have an application that will fill out the To/Subject/Body of an outlook email:

```
Dim App As New Outlook.Application
Dim MailItem As Outlook._MailItem = DirectCast(App.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem), Outlook._MailItem)


Dim appDataDir As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "\Microsoft\Signatures"
Dim Signature As String = String.Empty
Dim diInfo As New DirectoryInfo(appDataDir)

If diInfo.Exists Then
    Dim fiSignature As FileInfo() = diInfo.GetFiles("*.htm")
        If fiSignature.Length > 0 Then
            Dim sr As New StreamReader(fiSignature(0).FullName, Encoding.[Default])
            Signature = sr.ReadToEnd()

            If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Signature) Then
                Dim fileName As String = fiSignature(0).Name.Replace(fiSignature(0).Extension, String.Empty)
                Signature = Signature.Replace(fileName & Convert.ToString("_files/"), (Convert.ToString(appDataDir & Convert.ToString("/")) & fileName) + "_files/")
            End If
        End If
End If

With MailItem
    .To = "asdf"
    .Subject = "asdf"
    .Body = txtTemplatePreview.Text & vbNewLine
End With
MailItem.Display(True)
```

So the function of the first If Then statement is to append my default signature to the end of the email. However, when this code is run, the signature that is appended looks to be HTML code instead of the signature itself.

In addition, I'm told that the first If Then statement will fail if the user has more than one signature. Is there a way to circumvent this?

Comment: Work with - .HTMLBody

Comment: @0m3r That was it! Thanks! I'd love to mark your comment as the answer, so would you be able to post that as a reply?

Comment: Ah. Shoot. Turns out me doing .HTMLBody has messed with the formatting. I'll update original post.

Comment: Got it! Figured it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Work with **`HTMLBody Property`**

> *The property Returns or sets a String representing the HTML body of the specified item. The HTMLBody property should be an HTML syntax string. Read/write.*

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to do any of that - the signature is added automatically when Display is called if you do **not** set the Body or HTMLBody property before that.

Comment: Yes, this is true - I've tried it, but have been unable to add the email body after I call the display. Do you know of a way to?

Comment: You would need to merge the existing message body (with the newly added signature) and the new text. You can do that either using the Word Object Model (MailItem.GetInspector.WordEditor) or by reading the HTMLBody property and inserting your data after the body tag, then setting the HTMLBody back.